# How to make two files have the same access time using C?

Tags: c, linux, filesystems

I have two file paths; both point to a file, say 'abc.txt' and 'folder/cde.txt'

How can I make it so that abc.txt has the same access time as the other file?

I believe I can use `stat()` and `utime()` but I tried and failed.

Here's my code.

```
int myLink(const char *oldfile, const char *newfile)
{

    int result = link(oldfile, newfile);

    int ret;            /* return value */
    struct stat buf;        /* struct to hold file stats */
    ret = stat(oldfile, &buf);
    if (ret != 0) {
        perror("Failed:");
        exit(ret);
    }
    struct utimbuf puttime;
    puttime.modtime = buf.st_mtime;

    printf("\tatime: %d\n", buf.st_mtime);

    if (utime(newfile, &puttime))
        perror("utime");
    else
    {
        if (utime(extName, NULL))   /* set to current time */
            perror("utime");
    }

    return result;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Assuming you have two file names, then you don't want to use the `link()` system call.  If for some reason you do want to link the files, you need to worry about it return value (which will be an error if the second file already exists; you have to `unlink()` the new file name first).  Once the files are linked, they are two references to the same inode and inevitably have the same access time.

You then need to decide whether you want the first file to have the modification time of the second file or vice versa, or whether you want them both to have the same other access time (such as now, or some time in the past - or future!).

Assuming you want the second file's access time to be the same as the first file's access time (but the modification time of the second file to be unchanged), then you need to:

1. Collect the times of the first file.
2. Collect the times of the second file.
3. Create an appropriate `struct utimbuf` structure.
4. Call [`utime()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/utime.html).

Alternatively, for steps 3 and 4, you create an appropriate array of `struct timeval`, and use [`utimes()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/utimensat.html).

I'm intrigued (even puzzled) to see that the [`struct stat`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/basedefs/sys_stat.h.html#tag_13_62) in POSIX 2008 has no members `st_mtime`, `st_atime`, and `st_ctime` (of type `time_t`) any more: instead, it has `st_mtim`, `st_atim` and `st_ctim` of type `struct timeval`.  These allow for sub-second resolution on the timestamps.  I strongly suspect that the older members are typically present for reasons of backwards compatibility, if nothing else.

I am going to assume `st_mtime` and `st_atime` and `utime()` (and no linking).  This leads to revised code:

```
int myLink(const char *oldfile, const char *newfile)
{
    struct stat buf1;
    struct stat buf2;
    if (stat(oldfile, &buf1) != 0)
        return(-1);
    if (stat(newfile, &buf2) != 0)
        return(-1);
    struct utimbuf puttime;
    puttime.modtime = buf2.st_mtime;
    puttime.acttime = buf1.st_atime;
    return utime(newfile, &puttime);
}
```

If you want diagnostic printing, you can easily add it.  In general, library functions should not exit the program; it makes them unusable.  Diagnostic printing is also problematic - maybe you should not be writing to `stderr`, for example.

Comment: The code is - as yet - uncompiled, let alone tested.  Also, the function name is appallingly out of line with its actual purpose; it should be something like '`int set_atime_from_file(const char *reffile, const char *modfile)`'.

Answer (score 1):

If you create a hard link (using the `link` syscall) then there is only one file, and it has only one modification time and access time.  It can't be different from itself.

```
$ touch A
$ ln A B
$ ls -l A B
-rw-r--r-- 1 user group 0 Nov 2 0:00 A
-rw-r--r-- 1 user group 0 Nov 2 0:00 B
$ sleep 60
$ touch B
-rw-r--r-- 1 user group 0 Nov 2 0:01 A
-rw-r--r-- 1 user group 0 Nov 2 0:01 B
```

Note in the above example, there is only one file.  Both `A` and `B` are the same file.  The `ln` command just calls `link`.

Answer (score 0):

You are using `modtime` instead of `atime` and you're assigning a `timespec` to a `time_t`. You probably want:

```
puttime.actime = buf.st_atim.tv_sec;
                              ^^^^^^
```